# Find text files where the content is duplicated?

Tags: text-processing, grep, diff, text

By mistake I appended (>>) rather than overwrote (>) the output from a script that processed thousands of files, but I only did it for about 20 % of the files (I ran 5 parallel instances of the script). Basically I have ten lines of text, an empty line and then the same ten lines of text again.

1. How can I find these files?
2. How can I remove the second iteration?

1 is way more important than 2.

By mistake I appended (>>) rather than overwrote (>) the output from a script that processed thousands of files, but I only did it for about 20 % of the files (I ran 5 parallel instances of the script). Basically I have ten lines of text, an empty line and then the same ten lines of text again.

1. How can I find these files?
2. How can I remove the second iteration?

1 is way more important than 2.

(The problem is illustrated by this question)

---

Update:

I took a closer look at the content. This is how a file with duplicated content is structured:

```
<empty line>
<text>
<empty line>
<empty line>
<same text>
<empty line>
```

A file without duplicated content is

```
<empty line>
<text>
<empty line>
```

In other words, there are two empty lines in the middle, the origin of the first one is from the text above while the origin from the second one is the text below. The text is surrounded by one empty line both at the top and at the bottom.

Comment: Timestamp? Size comparison to backup?

Comment: Timestamp? No backup was made (it happened within an hour of the first time I tried. I can regenerate the content but it will take a day).

Comment: "ten lines of text" – Is ten a firm number or just an example? If the former then it's about files with 21 lines vs files with 10 (or 11?) lines.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It is a typical number. I don't think any of the files are longer than 100 lines, and most are probably 10-20 lines.

Comment: can your `<text>` contain any empty lines? i.e. is it always just one sentence/paragraph, or can it be multiple paragraphs?  Also, are there any instances where there are two or more sequential empty lines in <text>?

Comment: BTW, you said you didn't make a backup of the original data.  The absolute **first** thing you should do before anything else is to make a backup **NOW** (even a simple copy to another directory, or tar up the directory).  That way if you end up making things worse before you figure out a solution you can at least revert to the current less-than-ideal situation.   This, BTW, is good general advice: never work on your only copy of data you care about, especially if it is difficult, time-consuming, or impossible to get that data again - make a copy and work on the copy.

Comment: @cas No, no empty lines but a lot of new paragraphs. It is a kind of log file that starts with a time stamp followed by a message, new line and then another time stamp.

Comment: @cas I can regenerate the logs, that is easy, but very time and energy consuming.

Comment: ok, so you are absolutely certain that there will never be a case of a "good" file containing three newline (`\n`) characters in a row (i.e. a newline at the end of a line of actual text followed by two empty lines)?   If so, then try (on a **copy** of one of the "bad" files): `perl -i -0777 -p -e 's/\n{3,}.*/\n/' filename`

Comment: @cas You can never be absolutely sure but I am pretty certain that there never will be three \n in a row in a good file.

Comment: Even without backup, the timestamp looks like a good idea to identify the relevant files. Use `find` to find all files modified in the time range when the script was executed. This avoids accidently changing files that have duplicated content intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`, you can use the `$mapfile` associative array that maps file paths to their contents. That makes it easy to compare the first and second half and update the files in-place.

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/mapfile || exit
set +o multibyte

for file in **/*(ND.L+1); do
  text=$mapfile[$file]
  size=$#text
  if (( size % 2 == 0 )); then # even size
    (( half = size / 2 ))
    if [[ $text[1,half] = $text[half+1,-1] ]]; then
      print -r -- $file is one of them
      mapfile[$file]=$text[1,half] # or truncate -s$half -- $file
    fi
  fi
done
```

(untested).

You can replace `**/*(ND.L+0)` with `**/*(ND.L+0m-1)` to only process files last modified in the last 24 hours (or `**/*(ND.mh-3)` for the last 3 hours, etc). Remove the `D` if you don't need to consider hidden files. Remove or comment out the `mapfile[$file]=...` to only list the matching files without modifying them.

Comment: I added some more details about the structure of the text. Thank you.

Comment: Then that should be the second code. I've removed the first one.

Answer (score 0):

1. before you do anything else, make a backup of the data as it is now. If anything goes wrong, you can always revert to this copy. e.g. you could use `tar` to do this:

   ```
   tar cfz /path/to/backup-files.tar.gz /path/to/directory-to-backup/
   ```

   As a general rule, you should **never** work on your only copy of any data you care about.  Always make a backup, or make a copy and work on the copy.   In other words: you should **always** give yourself an easy, and preferably fast, way to revert any changes, undo any mistakes.
2. If you are absolutely certain that there will never be an instance of three newlines (`\n`) in a row in any of the "good" files, then try this on **copies** of some of the "good" AND "bad" files:

   ```
   perl -i -0777 -p -e 's/\n{3,}.*/\n\n/' filenames
   ```

   This will remove everything in those files starting from 3 newlines (i.e. a newline at the end of a line of text followed by two empty lines) to the end of the file, and replace it with two newlines (one to end the line of text, and one for the empty line you want at the end of the file).

   Any of the files which **don't** have 3 consecutive newlines (i.e. they're "good" files that don't need to be fixed), will not be modified.
3. Examine the files you just processed with perl (both "good" and "bad").

   If they're what you expect them to be, then run the perl script on all the files in the directory containing your files.  e.g. with `find` if the files all have `.txt` extensions:

   ```
   find /path/to/directory -type f -name '*.txt' -exec \
     perl -i -0777 -p -e 's/\n{3,}.*/\n\n/' {} +
   ```

   (adjust the `find` command to suit your actual directory and file names)

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```
find . -type f -size +1c -exec perl -l -0777 -e '
  while (<<>>) {
    $size = length; $half = $size / 2;
    if ($size % 2 == 0 && substr($_, 0, $half) eq substr($_, $half)) {
      print "$ARGV is one of them";
      truncate $ARGV, $half or warn "truncate $ARGV: $!";
    }
  }' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS and ENDFILE just to find the files:

```
$ awk -v RS='\n{2}' '$0==p{f=1} {p=$0} ENDFILE{print FILENAME, (f ? "dups" : "uniq"); p=f=""}' file1 file2
file1 dups
file2 uniq
```

The above was run on this input:

```
$ head file{1,2}
==> file1 <==

<text>


<text>


==> file2 <==

<text>
```